# Gunicorn can't access lets encrypt files

Tags: django, gunicorn, certbot

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-31-6-77:~/redrebelgames_python$ gunicorn redrebelgames_python.wsgi:application
[2021-11-25 20:01:09 +0000] [3758] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/redrebelgames_python/venv/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/ubuntu/redrebelgames_python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/redrebelgames_python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
    super().run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/redrebelgames_python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/redrebelgames_python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 198, in run
    self.start()
  File "/home/ubuntu/redrebelgames_python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 155, in start
    self.LISTENERS = sock.create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log, fds)
  File "/home/ubuntu/redrebelgames_python/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 162, in create_sockets
    raise ValueError('certfile "%s" does not exist' % conf.certfile)
ValueError: certfile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.redrebelgames.com/cert.pem" does not exist
```

How do I allow gunicorn to access these files? For some reason it's not working and simply changing the chmod permissions won't work because certbot will eventually change them back.

Answer (score 0):

The certbot files are owned by one identity (typically root). You are running Gunicorn under a different identity. The key is to grant permission to the Gunicorn identity to read the Let's Encrypt files. Typically you can add the Gunicorn username to the Let's Encrypt identity group name and make the files readable by the group.

Example command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupname username
```

The identity **username** must re-login after changing group membership. It is simpler to just restart the system.

Another method (not recommended) is to run Gunicorn as a privileged process. That has security risks.